# Difference between modification_time and change_time in fs::file_info()

Tags: r, file, filesystems, fs, file-attributes

The R package [fs](https://fs.r-lib.org/i) provides the function [`file_info()`](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/file_info.html) which returns a tibble containing i.a. the variables:

- `modification_time` The time of last data modification, as a POSIXct datetime.
- `access_time` The time of last access - as a POSIXct datetime.
- `change_time` The time of last file status change - as a POSIXct datetime.

Now I'm wondering **what are the differences between `modification_time` and `change_time`**?

What I noticed so far is that `change_time` seems to be immune to "chronological inconsistencies". Example:

```r
library(magrittr)
fs::file_create("test_file")
fs::file_info("test_file") %>% dplyr::select(modification_time, access_time, change_time)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   modification_time   access_time         change_time        
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 2019-10-24 13:23:35 2019-10-24 13:23:35 2019-10-24 13:23:35

# change access and modification times to current Sys.time()
# -> both modification_time and change_time will be updated
Sys.sleep(1)
fs::file_touch("test_file")
fs::file_info("test_file") %>% dplyr::select(modification_time, access_time, change_time)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   modification_time   access_time         change_time        
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 2019-10-24 13:23:37 2019-10-24 13:23:37 2019-10-24 13:23:37

# change access and modification times to the past (-2 min)
# -> only modification_time will be updated
fs::file_touch("test_file", Sys.time() - 120)
fs::file_info("test_file") %>% dplyr::select(modification_time, access_time, change_time)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   modification_time   access_time         change_time        
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 2019-10-24 13:21:37 2019-10-24 13:21:37 2019-10-24 13:23:37

# change  access and modification times to the future (+5 min)
# -> only modification_time will be updated
fs::file_touch("test_file", Sys.time() + 300)
fs::file_info("test_file") %>% dplyr::select(modification_time, access_time, change_time)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   modification_time   access_time         change_time        
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 2019-10-24 13:28:37 2019-10-24 13:28:37 2019-10-24 13:23:37
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The R base function `file.mtime()` only returns the `modification_time` from above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer is twofold:

1. The example above is misleading! The `change_time` always changes when `access_time` or `modification_time` is changed – it's just not perceptible from the output above because the time resolution is too low (seconds).
2. **`modification_time`** gives the **file modification timestamp**. This (as well as `access_time`) can be overwritten by the user employing tools like [`touch`](https://man.cx/touch) or the [`fs::file_touch()`](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/file_touch.html) function.

   **`change_time`** on the other hand gives the **metadata modification timestamp** and *can't be directly modified by the user*. Metadata refers to the last access time, last modification time, permissions and other properties [listed in this answer to another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385248/7196903).